# Adjacency matrices of multigraphs

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, adjacency-matrix

[image: Adj Matrix]
[image: Incidence Matrix]

Should the entry (adjacency matrix) for row = g, column = g be "2" instead of 1?

Also, should the entry (incidence matrix) for row = g, column = e11 be "2" instead of 1?

I have one lecturer saying that both entries should be "1" and another lecturer saying these two entries should have "2". This looks like it should be obvious; but, I've been given conflicting information about these entries and want to check if there is a "right" answer.

Comment: For the first question: because the graph is not directed, the entry should indeed be $2$. This is because one could go from $g$ to $g$ in $2$ ways on that line connecting $g$ to itself, as there is no specified direction to travel on that line. See the following link, and look at the undirected graphs section: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix

Comment: It shows that a loop on vertex 1 puts a "2" in row = 1, column = 1 (adjacency matrix); so, a loop gets "2" in the adjacency matrix for this type of graph.

Comment: Precisely. And because both ends of edge $e_{11}$ touch vertex $g$, we have that the $g,e_{11}$ entry should also be $2$ in the incidence graph.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the **degree sum formula** for a graph $G = (V,E)$,
$$\sum_{v \in V} \text{degree} \ v = 2|E|.$$
Now take a look at the multi-graph $G = (\{1\},\{1,1\})$. We obviously get a contradiction if we work with this definition of a self-loop ($\text{degree} \ v = 1$ for edge $\{v,v\}$).

Comment: Don't really know about multi-graphs. Only seen discrete mathematics for about one week. I'll be able to refer to your post later on.

Comment: @DoctorQuestions It is a graph with 1) potentially multiple edges between two vertices 2) self loops. So the graph in your question is a multi-graph.

Comment: I did a quick search and it said some authors don't allow loops in a multi-graph. The joys of basic discrete mathematics.

Comment: @DoctorQuestions We are discussing all entries $(a_{vv})_{v \in V}$. These are only non-zero in case of self loops...

Answer (score 0):

If there is a loop then the entry should be 2 instead of 1. For the incidence matrix, the sum of each column must always be 2.

Answer (score 0):

Recall the definition of an adjacency and incidence matrix.

In an adjacency matrix $A$, the rows and columns are indicated by vertices, and the entry $a_{ij}$ is the number of edges from vertices $v_i$ to $v_j$.

In an incidence matrix $B$, the rows are indicated by the vertices of the graph, and the columns are indicated by the edges of a graph, and the entry $b_{ij}$ is the number of times vertex $i$ is incident to edge $j$. In a directed graph, the convention of the outvertex contributing a +1 and an invertex contributing a -1 is usually adopted.

I presume you are asking what are the entries for a loop in these matrices.

We first approach the adjacency matrix.

The entry $A_{ii}$ in the adjacency matrix will be 2 in an undirected graph, viewing the start and end points as 2 different objects, rather than the same vertex. This is necessary for the degree-sum formula to be satisfied.

In directed graphs (unless both directions are indicated), this entry will be 1. Similarly, the degree-sum for directed graphs is also satisfied here.

For the incidence matrix, the following convention is usually adopted. For a loop $j$ on vertex $i$, the entry $B_{ij}$ will be 2 in an undirected graph and 0 in a directed one. This is similar in the previous case where we treat the start and end points as two different objects.